# Using * operator in function call

Tags: python

I am confused by the use of * in random.randint() and could not find any documentation

```
random.randint( *(1,300) )
```

vs

```
random.randint( 1,300 )

random.randint( *300 )
TypeError: randint() argument after * must be a sequence, not int
```

Comment: Is that the literal code? It'd make sense if it was `r = [1, 300]; random.randint(*r)`... But a literal tuple being unpacked it kind of odd... I think the link provided by @ecatmur is most likely the answer to your question

Comment: Yes its not the literal code. The tuple argument is passed to random.randint(). Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `*` in this context expands the tuple into separate elements. Whereas

```
random.randint( (1,300) )
```

would incorrectly pass a tuple as the single argument to `random.randint`,

```
random.randint( *(1,300) )
```

passes each element of the "decorated" tuple as an argument to the function. It's not really useful with a hard-coded tuple, since it would be faster and clearer to drop the `*` and the parentheses. However, when you have a name that references a tuple, it makes more sense.

```
range = (1,300)
random_value = random.randint( *range )
```

Answer (score 4):

The `*` is part of Python's [function call syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls).  The `*` takes an iterable and adds its elements to the parameters of the function call.

```
random.randint(*(1,300))
```

is the same thing as

```
random.randint(1,300)
```

The following is a syntax error, because `300` is not an iterable.

```
random.randint(*300)
```

The `*` syntax can sometimes be useful.  If you have a list (or some other iterable) `x` that contains the positional parameters that you want to use in a function call, you can either say:

```
func(x[0], x[1], x[2])
```

or, simply:

```
func(*x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of * in any python's function, means that the sequence that follows * is the arguments list to pass to the function. So,

```
random.randint(*(1, 300))
```

is the same that

```
random.randint(1, 300)
```

the code

```
random.randint(*300)
```

fails because 300 isn't a sequence it's an integer.